# Can I use get and set to read and write property in android just like C#

Tags: android

The following is a C# code, I can use get and set to read and write property eayily, can I do it in android? Thanks!

```
   public class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiredDate { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

C#'s compiler interprets these statements and generates classic get / set methods in IL. Java's compiler doesn't have an equivalent.

However, if you're interested in generating quick get/set statements for your instance members, using Eclipse, create a private member:

```
private int someVariable;
```

When a warning symbol appears under it, stating you're not using this variable, right click on it, then select the "generate get/set methods".

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Android typically uses a derivative of Java, and will not recognize such code.